# Multiple Terminals?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm certain the answer is out there somewhere, but afaict there's just too much DLC hype for me to find it...
I'm trying to set up three separate Ammunition Plants at my one Settlement on Spectacle Island. I want them all making different kinds of ammunition.

The problem is, no matter how I wire them, how far apart I put them, wherever I put a terminal, it controls all three plants and will set them all to the same ammunition.

I really don't want to have to go and give them each their own power generator, so is there a better solution? Is there ANY sane way to prevent the Terminals controlling my entire settlement so I can compartmentalize things a bit?

Answer (score 1):

If any two things are connected by the same power wires, then a terminal will control them both.

This includes any power systems. As such, each ammunition plant will have to be on it's own power system. This likely also includes having separate conveyor belt lines, as the conveyor belts transfer power along themselves and I'm not sure if that would count for terminal control.

Comment: There's a mod that lets you build [insulated power pylons](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4277/?), but you'll still need to have separate generators.